# Find similar/related documents (pages) using SP Search/FAST SP Search (2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, fast-for-sharepoint

I've previously used the [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) ([javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/index.html)) feature in Solr and I'm trying to find out of the same capability is available in SP Server Search or FAST SP Search.

If you haven't used Solr/MoreLikeThis; it constructs a lucene query using the terms in the document you are currently viewing and finds similar documents. I want to do the same in SP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a concept of "similar" documents in FAST Search for SharePoint 2010. The functionality is exposed through the SharePoint [query object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.keywordquery_members.aspx) as well as the [query web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872313.aspx). [FAST Search Query Integration Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394628.aspx) MSDN article contains a reference to [Find Similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521597.aspx) that covers the concept in more details. Basically, you'll need to set the `SimilarTo`, `SimilarType` and `SortSimilar` property values when executing your query programmatically.